# Mouse events are not detecting other div which is on another div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding mouseover event. According to my HTML code, the `myDiv` is appearing exactly on `<img>`. I am detecting mouseover on both `<img>` and `myDiv`.

But what happens, when I hover a mouse on `<img>` its working fine and it's detecting that it's hovered on image but when I hover on `myDiv` without leaving  `<img>`, it's not detecting `myDiv`, it's still in `<img>`. How can I detect myDiv without leaving img.

Below is my code

 
My HTML code

```
<style>
 .myDiv{
     position:absolute;
  }
 .hoverEffect{
     border: 2px solid #0044ff;
     opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>
<div class="myDiv">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<img src="myimage.jpg">
```

JQuery Code

```
$('body').mouseover(function(e) {
      //e.target For Detecting div or image
      $(e.target).addClass('hoverEffect');
});
$('body').mouseout(function(e) {
     $(e.target).removeClass('hoverEffect');
}
```

In below GIF image, you can see content "WELCOME TO OUR APP" in above image. And after hovering on image, it's not detecting this content which has another div.

**Updated Information**
In above JQuery code, I've added the class "`hoverEffect`" to hovered `div`. The only problem is in `hoverEffect` class and that is opacity. When I use opacity then it's not detecting `myDiv` but when I remove opacity from css code then it's working fine. 

[Working jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8sbxhqgd/) (without using opacity) 
[Not Working jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/w6ezx38a/2/) (with opacity)

My question is, why it's not working when I add opacity to the class?
If it's possible to do it without removing opacity from class then how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did You tried z-index css property to  take div front of img?

```
.myDiv{
  z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect every element inside `body`, move your mouse and see at the console. Here is an example:

```js
$('body').mouseover(function(e) {
     console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
.myDiv{ 
  position:absolute;  
  background-color:violet;
}

h1 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">
```

Comment: I have checked the console but it's not detecting myDiv once I hover on IMG and  then hover on myDiv. It's working only when I keep myDiv at corner or at edge of image . But when I move myDiv to center of image then it's not working

Comment: @Commertial In above gif image, you can see  there is blue border is displaying for image when mouse hover on image. Same border is not displaying for myDiv on hover

Comment: @Onkar, may be it's because you forgot to declare `:hover` behavior for that div?